# How to add x seconds to a Python datetime64[ns] field?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in Python with the following fields and types:

```
sent         datetime64[ns]
tz_offset             int64
```

and I want to go through my data frame and add the offset (which is in seconds) to the sent field.

How can I do this? I have tried the following:

```
files['sent'] = files['sent'].apply(lambda x: x + np.timedelta64(files['tz_offset']), 's')
```

but this is failing with the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-e47a813beced> in <module>()
      1 #np.datetime64('2009') + np.timedelta64(20, 's')
----> 2 files['sent'] = files['sent'].apply(lambda x: x + np.timedelta64(files['tz_offset']), 's')

/Users/myhome/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2167             values = lib.map_infer(values, lib.Timestamp)
   2168 
-> 2169         mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2170         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
   2171             from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:62578)()

<ipython-input-80-e47a813beced> in <lambda>(x)
      1 #np.datetime64('2009') + np.timedelta64(20, 's')
----> 2 files['sent'] = files['sent'].apply(lambda x: x + np.timedelta64(files['tz_offset']), 's')

ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta
```

EDITED: Using Pandas

Comment: You're using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorized approach is to convert type and add, `df['sent'] + df['tz_offset'].astype("timedelta64[s]")`

```
In [346]: df
Out[346]:
                 sent  tz_offset
0 2011-01-01 00:00:00          2
1 2011-01-01 00:01:00          0
2 2011-01-01 00:02:00          4
3 2011-01-01 00:03:00          0
4 2011-01-01 00:04:00          4
5 2011-01-01 00:05:00          4
6 2011-01-01 00:06:00          4
7 2011-01-01 00:07:00          1
8 2011-01-01 00:08:00          4
9 2011-01-01 00:09:00          4

In [347]: df['sent'] + df['tz_offset'].astype("timedelta64[s]")
Out[347]:
0   2011-01-01 00:00:02
1   2011-01-01 00:01:00
2   2011-01-01 00:02:04
3   2011-01-01 00:03:00
4   2011-01-01 00:04:04
5   2011-01-01 00:05:04
6   2011-01-01 00:06:04
7   2011-01-01 00:07:01
8   2011-01-01 00:08:04
9   2011-01-01 00:09:04
dtype: datetime64[ns]


In [348]: df.dtypes
Out[348]:
sent         datetime64[ns]
tz_offset             int32
dtype: object
```

or using `apply` on `np.timedelta64()`

```
In [349]: df.apply(lambda x: x['sent'] + np.timedelta64(x['tz_offset'], 's'), axis=1)
Out[349]:
0   2011-01-01 00:00:02
1   2011-01-01 00:01:00
2   2011-01-01 00:02:04
3   2011-01-01 00:03:00
4   2011-01-01 00:04:04
5   2011-01-01 00:05:04
6   2011-01-01 00:06:04
7   2011-01-01 00:07:01
8   2011-01-01 00:08:04
9   2011-01-01 00:09:04
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

or, use `pd.offsets.timedelta(seconds=)` aka `pd.Timedelta(seconds=)`

```
In [350]: df.apply(lambda x: x['sent'] + pd.Timedelta(seconds=x['tz_offset']), axis=1)
Out[350]:
0   2011-01-01 00:00:02
1   2011-01-01 00:01:00
2   2011-01-01 00:02:04
3   2011-01-01 00:03:00
4   2011-01-01 00:04:04
5   2011-01-01 00:05:04
6   2011-01-01 00:06:04
7   2011-01-01 00:07:01
8   2011-01-01 00:08:04
9   2011-01-01 00:09:04
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```